# Why does every record get the same random value on update?

Tags: mysql

I want to populate a column (rnd_order) with a random and unique integer value. 
The 2nd Query below generates a random value but it stores the same value in every row. What am I doing wrong there?

```
UPDATE profiles2 SET rnd_order = 1;

UPDATE
`profiles2`
SET
  rnd_order =
              (SELECT rid FROM
                        (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 199999) AS rid FROM
                                 `profiles2` WHERE "rnd_order" NOT IN
                                           (SELECT rnd_order FROM
                                                    `profiles2`) LIMIT 1) q);
```

Explain

```
1,UPDATE,profiles2,,ALL,,,,,46901,100.00,
2,UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY,,,,,,,,,,no matching row in const table
3,DERIVED,,,,,,,,,,Impossible WHERE
4,SUBQUERY,profiles2,,index_subquery,rnd_order,rnd_order,5,const,2,100.00,Using index
```

Comment: Did you try `UPDATE profiles2 SET rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 199999);`?

Comment: @nenad007 but you don't get the same value in all rows with that. Correct?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes correct I got mostly different values

Comment: @nenad007 - Is "mostly different" good enough?  If so, why isn't ypercube's answer "good enough"?

Comment: "random" and "unique" are contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a solution where I got a unique value to be able to sort the records and be able to paginate.

A solution where I should do looping is, in my case, not usable.

The following solution works consistently and solved this for me in a clean way:

```
UPDATE `profiles2` SET rnd_order = NULL;

SET @r := 100000;

UPDATE  `profiles`
SET     rnd_order = (@r := @r + 1)
ORDER BY
    RAND();
```

Comment: While this solution does introduce some sort of manually created random number, it is not random in these sense of the `RAND()` function.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute that query, the random value gets chosen once, at the start of query execution, and applied to every row.

You need to use a function that is evaluated for each row.

In SQL Server, I'd use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()`... Perhaps [`RANDOM_BYTES()` would work in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes).

Answer (score 3):

How about looping until unique?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE se198131 \G
-- (id is already set up with 1..1000)
-- Populate `rnd_order`:
UPDATE se198131 SET rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 19999);
-- Sample of data:
SELECT * FROM se198131 LIMIT 5;
-- Sample of dups:
SELECT rnd_order, COUNT(*) AS ct  FROM se198131
    GROUP BY rnd_order
    HAVING ct > 1
    ORDER BY ct DESC
    LIMIT 5;
-- Fix some of the dups:
UPDATE se198131 JOIN ( 
    SELECT rnd_order, MAX(id) AS id
        FROM se198131
        GROUP BY rnd_order
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                     ) x  USING(id)
    SET se198131.rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 19999);
-- See that there are fewer dups:
SELECT rnd_order, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM se198131
    GROUP BY rnd_order
    HAVING ct > 1
    ORDER BY ct DESC
    LIMIT 5;
-- Repeat this until no more dups:
UPDATE se198131 JOIN ( 
    SELECT rnd_order, MAX(id) AS id
        FROM se198131
        GROUP BY rnd_order
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                     ) x  USING(id)
    SET se198131.rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 19999);
```

Testing:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE se198131 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: se198131
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `se198131` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rnd_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- (id is already set up with 1..1000)
-- Populate `rnd_order`:

```
mysql> UPDATE se198131 SET rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 19999);
Query OK, 1000 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1000  Changed: 1000  Warnings: 0
```

-- Sample of data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM se198131 LIMIT 5;
+----+-----------+
| id | rnd_order |
+----+-----------+
|  0 |     15202 |
|  1 |      3751 |
|  2 |     13146 |
|  3 |     14481 |
|  4 |     12969 |
+----+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- Sample of dups:

```
mysql> SELECT rnd_order, COUNT(*) AS ct  FROM se198131
    ->     GROUP BY rnd_order
    ->     HAVING ct > 1
    ->     ORDER BY ct DESC
    ->     LIMIT 5;
+-----------+----+
| rnd_order | ct |
+-----------+----+
|     15164 |  2 |
|     18953 |  2 |
|     12490 |  2 |
|     10522 |  2 |
|     19117 |  2 |
+-----------+----+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

-- Fix some of the dups:

```
mysql> UPDATE se198131 JOIN ( 
    ->     SELECT rnd_order, MAX(id) AS id
    ->         FROM se198131
    ->         GROUP BY rnd_order
    ->         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ->                      ) x  USING(id)
    ->     SET se198131.rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 19999);
Query OK, 27 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 27  Changed: 27  Warnings: 0
```

-- See that there are fewer dups:

```
mysql> SELECT rnd_order, COUNT(*) AS ct
    ->     FROM se198131
    ->     GROUP BY rnd_order
    ->     HAVING ct > 1
    ->     ORDER BY ct DESC
    ->     LIMIT 5;
+-----------+----+
| rnd_order | ct |
+-----------+----+
|      5638 |  2 |
|      2886 |  2 |
|     10142 |  2 |
+-----------+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- Repeat until no more dups:

```
mysql> UPDATE se198131 JOIN ( 
    ->     SELECT rnd_order, MAX(id) AS id
    ->         FROM se198131
    ->         GROUP BY rnd_order
    ->         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ->                      ) x  USING(id)
    ->     SET se198131.rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 19999);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0
```

-- Repeat until no more dups:

```
mysql> UPDATE se198131 JOIN ( 
    ->     SELECT rnd_order, MAX(id) AS id
    ->         FROM se198131
    ->         GROUP BY rnd_order
    ->         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ->                      ) x  USING(id)
    ->     SET se198131.rnd_order = FLOOR(RAND() * 19999);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

"Changed: 0", so quit.